# Trying to reset my database due to a bugged migration, can't even reset without SQLException

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rake

I was trying to fix a bad migration, I ended up jsut deleting it but I can't even reset my rails db now. I just get this error:

I was using this command to reset and re-run:

> rake db:reset db:migrate

The error:

> rake db:reset rake aborted! ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: simulations: SELECT 
>   "simulations".* FROM "simulations"  ORDER BY "simulations"."id" DESC
>   LIMIT 1

These are the migrations I have
1.

```
 class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => "", limit: 96
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => "", limit: 60

      t.timestamps

      t.index :email, unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

2.

```
class CreateSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Needs the hash column worked out before this is run 
    create_table :simulations do |t|
        t.integer :x_size
        t.integer :y_size
        t.string :verdict
        t.string :arrangement 
    end

    add_reference :simulations, :user, index: true    
  end
end
```

3.

```
    class AddOpinionToSimulation < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :simulations, :opinion, :hash
      end
    end
```

Finally the bad one I was trying to run that started these problems (I have deleted the file to stop it from attempting to be migrated:

```
class RemoveVerdictFromSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :simulations, :verdict
  end
end
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Full trace:

> Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro:clio-hiring-ui nathanielmots$ rake db:drop
>   db:create db:migrate rake aborted! ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: simulations: SELECT 
>   "simulations".* FROM "simulations"  ORDER BY "simulations"."id" DESC
>   LIMIT 1
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `initialize'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`
>   new'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `prepare'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:296:in`block in exec_query'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:293:in`exec_query'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:347:in
>   `select'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in`
>   select_all'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in
>   `select_all'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in`
>   find_by_sql'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:638:in
>   `exec_queries'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:514:in`
>   load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in
>   `to_a'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:523:in`
>   find_last'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:172:in
>   `last'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in`
>   last'
>   /Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/clio-hiring-ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:16:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in`instance_eval'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `factory'
>   /Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/clio-hiring-ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:15:in`
>   block in '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in`run'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in
>   `define'
>   /Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/clio-hiring-ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:14:in`
>   '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`block in load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in`each'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in`each'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:21:in`
>   block in '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in
>   `call'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in`
>   execute_hook'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in
>   `block in run_load_hooks'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`
>   each'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in
>   `run_load_hooks'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in`
>   block in '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `instance_exec'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   run'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
>   `block in run_initializers'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   run_initializers'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in
>   `initialize!'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in`
>   public_send'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in
>   `method_missing'
>   /Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/clio-hiring-ui/config/environment.rb:5:in`
>   '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in
>   `require_environment!'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in`
>   block in run_tasks_blocks' SQLite3::SQLException: no such table:
>   simulations
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `initialize'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`
>   new'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `prepare'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:296:in`block in exec_query'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:293:in`exec_query'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:347:in
>   `select'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in`
>   select_all'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in
>   `select_all'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in`
>   find_by_sql'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:638:in
>   `exec_queries'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:514:in`
>   load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in
>   `to_a'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:523:in`
>   find_last'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:172:in
>   `last'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in`
>   last'
>   /Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/clio-hiring-ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:16:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in`instance_eval'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `factory'
>   /Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/clio-hiring-ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:15:in`
>   block in '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in`run'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in
>   `define'
>   /Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/clio-hiring-ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:14:in`
>   '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`block in load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in`each'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in`each'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:21:in`
>   block in '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in
>   `call'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in`
>   execute_hook'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in
>   `block in run_load_hooks'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`
>   each'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in
>   `run_load_hooks'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in`
>   block in '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `instance_exec'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   run'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
>   `block in run_initializers'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   run_initializers'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in
>   `initialize!'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in`
>   public_send'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in
>   `method_missing'
>   /Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/clio-hiring-ui/config/environment.rb:5:in`
>   '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in
>   `require_environment!'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in`
>   block in run_tasks_blocks' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment

Edit @Ian:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: simulations
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  x_size      :integer
#  y_size      :integer
#  verdict     :string
#  arrangement :string
#  user_id     :integer
#  opinion     :hash
#

FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :simulation do |f|
        f.id (Simulation.last.nil? ? 1 : Simulation.last.id + 1)
        f.x_size 3
        f.y_size 3
        f.user_id 1
    end 
end
```

Comment: What makes you think the last migration was "bad"? It should have separate up and down methods, the latter to recreate the column, but removing a column is a perfectly valid migration...

Comment: I think it was bad because no 'my_sym' error you normally get when doing a migration with bad spelling as seen : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634557/on-migration-undefined-method-to-sym-for-nilnilclass

Comment: Could there be something in an initialiser or something that is querying the simulations table? The rest of the backtrace may be informative.

Comment: Why are factory girl factories being called? You've got a line in the stack trace that's really odd: `/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/clio-hiring-ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:14`

what's going on in line 14 of that file?

Answer (score 0):

`db:reset` does a `db:drop db:setup`. `db:setup` does a `schema:load`, which is trying to read your db schema file, which probably has the issue. If you do `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`, that should fix it.

More info in this answer: [Difference between rake db:migrate db:reset and db:schema:load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload)

Comment: This is still causing the same error.. can you see whats wrong with any of those migrations ?