# Rails migration error - SQLite database unable to remove or add column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to make changes to a table in the database of my Rails app and I'm encountering the following issue -

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  to_s/Users/Michael/MWCoding/MamaKnows/mama_knows/db/migrate/20160415190242_remove_organiser_description_from_events.rb:3:in`change'
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  to_s

I've tried rollback and migrate:redo and I'm getting nothing and fear that I now have no choice but to do a drop. I believe the mistake was following an earlier migration where I used an incorrect column type.

How do I move forward from here? I'm fairly new to Rails and have never completed a database drop before so a little unsure of the procedure. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Code from last migration from the error code -

```
class RemoveOrganiserDescriptionFromEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :events, :organiser_description, :text
  end
end
```

Events Table -

```
    class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :location
      t.date :date
      t.time :time
      t.text :description
      t.string :organised_by
      t.text :organiser_description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The events table does not show in the schema.rb file, in its place I have the following text -

```
# Could not dump table "events" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

From SQLite, having run PRAGMA table_info(events);

```
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
1|title|varchar|0||0
2|location|varchar|0||0
3|date|date|0||0
4|time|time|0||0
5|description|text|0||0
6|organised_by|varchar|0||0
7|created_at|datetime|1||0
8|updated_at|datetime|1||0
9|user_id|integer|0||0
10|image_file_name|varchar|0||0
11|image_content_type|varchar|0||0
12|image_file_size|integer|0||0
13|image_updated_at|datetime|0||0
14|category_id|integer|0||0
15|url|varchar|0||0
16|number_of_spaces|integer|0||0
17|price|integer|0||0
18|is_free|boolean|0||0
19|organiser_profile|url|0||0
```

Comment: please post the migration code.

Comment: Do you mean the trace?

Comment: I mean the code in this migration:
`mama_knows/db/migrate/20160415190242_remove_organiser_description_from_events.rb`

Comment: class RemoveOrganiserDescriptionFromEvents <     ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        remove_column :events, :organiser_description, :text
      end
    end

Comment: That didn't come through very well - I've added it in the question above.

Comment: Hi i just double check in my pc and :text is not the source of your problems, 
it must be something else but i cant say what it is with the information you provided. 
i will delete my answer by now and post again when i have a better idea on how can you solve this problem.

Comment: take a look if this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634557/on-migration-undefined-method-to-sym-for-nilnilclass) helps you

Comment: Do you need any further information?

Comment: hummm could you check on events table if theres not a typo on  organiser_description field?

Comment: I've put the events table in my question above - doesn't appear to be a spelling mistake. In my schema.rb file the events table is not showing, instead I have the following text - # Could not dump table "events" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: run this to confirm theres no typo enter sqlite `sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3` then run  `PRAGMA table_info(events);`

Comment: yes in the terminal.

Comment: I've put the results in my question text above. The listing No19 is the one I put the wrong type on (organiser_profile - url). I can't see any typo errors - could it be this mistake that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the wrong attribute organiser_profile on migration file then if drop database is not a issue for you do in the command line:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: Should I start a completely fresh migration or update that migration file by deleting the type? I've already tried a rollback so it might be a dead file anyway.

Comment: There is no typo on the above. Should I delete the erroneous entry in the table above (organiser_profile - url) and if so how do I do this on the command line?

Comment: Okay, I don't think I have a huge amount in the db so it won't be an issue. What is the command to check what is in the database before I do the drop?

Comment: check this [firefox pluggin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)